# Convert CST to UTC

Tags: python, datetime

How can I convert the CST to UTC by this code?

```
str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")) + "Z"
```

This is the predefined and my UI is in CST and API want to be in UTC. So, how can I convert CST to UTC using same code?

Answer (score 0):

One comment upfront: if you are actually using `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`, you don't need to do any conversion.  That is the UTC time, though it is technically a naive datetime because it does not have a `.tzinfo` attribute attached.  (And you also don't need to call `str`.)

---

Otherwise, assuming that your input time is actually local-based (does not use `.utcnow()`), you can use `time.timezone` to get a timedelta.  Here is an example from my system, which is EST:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time

>>> localtime = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> localtime
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 13, 13, 22, 54, 109529)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 13, 18, 23, 3, 373213)

>>> convrt = localtime + datetime.timedelta(
...     seconds=time.timezone)
>>> 
>>> convrt
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 13, 18, 22, 54, 109529)
>>> convrt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
'2018-11-13T18:22:54.109529+00:00'
```

Notice that `.isoformat()` uses the numeric offset.  To get the name, use `%Z`:

```
>>> convrt.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")
'2018-11-13T18:22:54UTC'
```

`time.timezone` is an offset of the local (non-DST) timezone, in seconds west of UTC.  There's also `time.altzone`, which is offset of the local DST timezone (seconds west).

Comment: That's a good solution but I can't write my scripts in the python file. I've to use existed code. That is like I posted in the Question. I've to change only the code by adding the something like this: 
str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")[-3]) + "Z"